# Using CSS, how to add a pseudo element before every odd child element that is "outside" of that child element?

Tags: css

I want to create a grid with two columns whose width will be equal. My base HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="linkgrid">
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Loooooooooooooong</a>
  </div>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Short</a>
  </div>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Meeeedium</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, the first and the second `gridentry` should lie in the the first row. The thrid `gridentry` should lie in the second row. All `gridentry`s should have the same width.

~~~

I came up with a solution that uses a CSS table. However, to make sure the row "breaks" after every second cell, it currently requires non-semantic elements to force these "row breaks":

```css
.linkgrid {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
}

.gridentry {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.gridentry a {
  color: white;
}

.THIS-SHOULD-BE-A-PSEUDO-ELEMENT-BEFORE-EVERY-ODD-CHILD {
/* I imagine a selector that looks somewhat like this:
.linkgrid .gridentry:nth-child(odd):outsidebefore {
*/
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkgrid">
  <span class="THIS-SHOULD-BE-A-PSEUDO-ELEMENT-BEFORE-EVERY-ODD-CHILD"></span>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Loooooooooooooong</a>
  </div>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Short</a>
  </div>
  <span class="THIS-SHOULD-BE-A-PSEUDO-ELEMENT-BEFORE-EVERY-ODD-CHILD"></span>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Meeeedium</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to remove my `<span>`s from my HTML (because they do not have any semantics) and use a clever CSS selector that adds them as pseudo elements at the right positions instead?

I do know that `:before` will "create" a pseudo-element *within* the selected element. Is there a non-JavaScript, CSS-only way to add a pseudo-element *outside* of the selected element like required in this example?

---

**Another edit:** For all those familiar with the Chrome developer tools, I want my result to look somewhat like this in the DOM tree:

```
<div class="linkgrid">
  ::outsidebefore
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Loooooooooooooong</a>
  </div>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Short</a>
  </div>
  ::outsidebefore
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Meeeedium</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

...where the `::outsidebefore` pseudo-elements should have the CSS property `display: table-row;`.

---

**Update 2016-01-04:** While this specific question remains unanswered, my original problem was solved another way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34588007/1560865

So please only post replies to this question that answer precisely the given question.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't cause the `<span>` elements to show; so we can't see where you want the pseudo elements to appear on the rendered page.

Comment: If you want to remove elements from your HTML, or re-add removed elements, then you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Basically..."NO"...pseudo-elements are always *inside* their related elements. You'll have to find another way...perhaps "Flexbox".

Comment: @DavidThomas: The `<span>`s are intentionally left empty - they're just there to force a row break, i.e. the cells following a `<span>` should start in the next row. I didn't find a better way to make sure that my semantic HTML code will be displayed in two columns with equal widths.

Comment: I just added more details to my question. Hopefully it will be clearer now what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @MrLister: Could you give an example what you mean with using CSS table rows? (Also thanks for pointing out that something like `::outside` was considered once.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display Level 3 introduces [`display: contents`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-contents):

> The element itself does not generate any boxes, but its children and
>   pseudo-elements still generate boxes as normal. For the purposes of
>   box generation and layout, the element must be treated as if it had
>   been replaced with its children and pseudo-elements in the document
>   tree.

Then, you can:

1. Wrap each cell in a container element
2. Set `display: contents` to those containers
3. Add `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements to those containers

The result will look like as if the pseudo-elements were added to the cell, but outside it.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: contents;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(odd)::before {
  content: '';
  display: table-row;
}
```

```css
.linkgrid {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: contents;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(odd)::before {
  content: '';
  display: table-row;
}
.gridentry {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.gridentry a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkgrid">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="gridentry">
      <a href="#">Loooooooooooooong</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="gridentry">
      <a href="#">Short</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="gridentry">
      <a href="#">Meeeedium</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note `display: contents` is not widely supported yet, but works on Firefox.

Comment: I'll wait before accepting this as the final answer until there is acceptable browser support for this.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is using an actual table structure. That is, one table divided into rows, in which the entries sit.
Also, you had `width:50%` on the table, but I believe from the question text that you meant every table cell to be 50% wide, rather than the table taking up 50% of the window width; so I corrected that.

```css
.linkgrid {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 2px;
}
.gridrow {                     /* new */
  display: table-row;
}
.gridentry {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;                  /* moved */
}
.gridentry a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkgrid">
  <div class="gridrow">
    <div class="gridentry">
      <a href="#">Loooooooooooooong</a>
    </div>
    <div class="gridentry">
      <a href="#">Short</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gridrow">
    <div class="gridentry">
      <a href="#">Meeeedium</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it introduces new `<div>`s - and I wanted to avoid just that. (That's what I meant with a CSS-only solution.) But thank you in any way!

Comment: Well, you were introducing new spans attempting to do the same.

Comment: Yeah - I just used them as a demonstration for what I wanted to achieve in the end. After all, I wanted to remove those `<span>`s from the HTML code - and kind of re-introduce them as CSS pseudo-elements instead.

Comment: To avoid introducing new HTML elements to serve as table rows, don't use tables at all. Make the grid entries `display:inline-block` and then you can use `nth-child(even)::after` for the "line breaks". Of course then you won't have the luxury of every entry being the width of the widest content...

Comment: Thanks again - I guess that should be an answer to my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566890/using-css-how-to-create-a-two-column-grid-with-equal-width-columns-that-are-as However, how could I use CSS to make sure that all `inline-block`s have the same width?

Comment: If you're desperate, use JavaScript to determine the width of the widest gridentry and set every gridentry to that width.

Comment: Yeah, that would be my last resort. But that makes it even "less CSS-only".

Comment: Then take a guess at what the maximum width will be, and use that for a width in the stylesheet.