# Using CSS, how to create a two-column grid with equal-width columns that are "only as narrow as required"?

Tags: css

Assuming I have a piece of HTML that is structured like this:

```
<!-- MY ACTUAL HTML -->

<div class="linkgrid">
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Loooooooooooooong</a>
  </div>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Short</a>
  </div>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Meeeedium</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

...I'd like to make use of CSS to get a presentation that looks like this:

```css
/* DEMONSTRATION-ONLY CSS */

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1em;

  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

td a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- DEMONSTRATION-ONLY HTML -->

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Loooooooooooooong</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Short</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Meeeedium</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that:

1. The columns both have the same width.
2. The table does not have a fixed width (e.g. like 100% or 300px), i.e. it is only as wide as required to make sure that the content fits into its cells. (Or to put it differently: If there is only little content, the whole table will also be pretty narrow.)
3. The cell content will only wrap if it would make the whole grid too large to fit into the containing block (width-wise).
4. We have to assume that rows cannot be introduced in the HTML code. The semantics require the HTML code to be structured in this linear fashion. (However, we still need a grid design.)<sup>1</sup>

I was able to reach my goal with an almost CSS-only solution. However, because there does not seem to be an answer to [Using CSS, how to add a pseudo element before every odd child element that is "outside" of that child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559771/using-css-how-to-add-a-pseudo-element-before-every-odd-child-element-that-is-o) I hope to find a completely different approach to realize this with pure CSS.

So my question boils down to: Is there a CSS-only (= non-JavaScript) solution for my problem?

---

**EDIT:** <sup>1</sup> If it is required, we could add additional wrapping elements around each single element. However, we cannot wrap a group of elements.

So we could for example wrap each `gridentry`:

```
<div class="linkgrid">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="gridentry">
      <a href="#">Loooooooooooooong</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="gridentry">
      <a href="#">Short</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="gridentry">
      <a href="#">Meeeedium</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But we cannot wrap groups of elements, so something like this would not be possible:

```
<div class="linkgrid">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="gridentry">
      <a href="#">Loooooooooooooong</a>
    </div>
    <div class="gridentry">
      <a href="#">Short</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="gridentry">
      <a href="#">Meeeedium</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One solution is to use JavaScript to insert table rows (well, dives acting as table rows) around every pair of entries.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  Here's the closest I can come, but you can see from my notes that it's breaking down: https://jsfiddle.net/7c5mjd7o/2/

Comment: the best (maybe the worse) i could think of, is a flexbox approach http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yegVrm

Comment: Looks promising! However, if the Looooong content gets really loooooong, it stops working properly.

Comment: @GCyrillus - looks like it suffers from the same issue my approach did - add more cells, and the grid keeps getting wider.  It's as if the browser can't keep up with the 50% calculation: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgRNXM

Comment: @cale_b would word-wrap and/or  break-word  be a turnaround ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yegVrm http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BjpQXq

Comment: @GCyrillus - not sure.  The issue (as I see it) is that the "cells" stretch wider the more "cells" that you add, even though the content inside isn't any wider.  At small sizes (3-4 elements) it holds together fine, but starts getting too wide when you have many "cells".

Comment: @cale_b , right, funny behavior ... that is

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. Putting percentage-width flex boxes into tables with unspecified widths seems to cause some very strange behavior. After fiddling around for a while and running into a lot more mysterious things, I came up with just another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572022/why-do-percentage-width-sized-flex-box-items-not-properly-increase-the-width-of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just revisited this now since CSS Grid has become much more supported. One solution for CSS Grid would be this:

```css
.linkgrid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
}

.gridentry > * {
  display: block;

  padding: 10px;

  text-align: center;
  
  background-color: red;
  color: white;

  /* This is helpful if the texts get too long to break them "naturally": */
  /* word-break: break-all; */
}
```

```html
<div class="linkgrid">
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Loooooooooooooong</a>
  </div>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Short</a>
  </div>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Meeeedium</a>
  </div>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Short</a>
  </div>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Short</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling around with this for quite a while and getting [a very helpful answer to another question that was related to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34572042/1560865), I managed to finally find a solution:

```css
.linkgrid {
  max-width: 50%;
  display: table;
}

.gridentry:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.gridentry:nth-child(even) {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
}

.gridentry:nth-child(even):after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: left;
}

.gridentry > * {
  display: block;
  
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;

  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;

  /* This is helpful if the texts get too long to break them "naturally": */
  /* word-break: break-all; */
}

.gridentry:nth-child(odd) > * {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.gridentry:nth-child(even) > * {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.gridentry a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkgrid">
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Loooooooooooooong</a>
  </div>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Short</a>
  </div>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Meeeedium</a>
  </div>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Short</a>
  </div>
  <div class="gridentry">
    <a href="#">Short</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This mix of tables, floats and margins seems so hacky but I love it!

Comment: this sux ... float is one of the worst things you can use .. and with the combination of tables ... c'mon ... maybe in 90s

Comment: ...or in 2016. ;-) Back then, grid was not very well supported. So that was the only real option that I was able to find.