# Why do percentage-width-sized flex box items not properly increase the width of a wrapping table that has an unspecified (i.e. auto) width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Please take a look at this snippet:

```css
table {
  background-color: yellow;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px red;
  max-width: 100%;
  
  /* You would get similarly strange behavior with collapsing borders: */
  /* border-collapse: collapse; */
}

td {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px blue;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.flex {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius: 9px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="box">
          123456789ABCDEFGHIJKL
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          meeedium
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          short
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*(Here's a codepen if you want to play with it more easily: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKJmBM)*

Please note that the text in the upper left `box` does not completely fit into it. (At least in Chrome it does not.) I was assuming that the wrapping table would try to "push" its width in order for its contents to completely fit into itself. So is this an implementation bug? Or an unspecified behavior? Or is my code simply flawed?

Can someone explain this behavior and provide a solution to fix it?

(By the way... I ran into this strange behavior while experimenting with some initial solution sketches for this question: [Using CSS, how to create a two-column grid with equal-width columns that are "only as narrow as required"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566890/using-css-how-to-create-a-two-column-grid-with-equal-width-columns-that-are-on))

---

**Edit:** The two "visual columns" should both have an equal width. Therefore solutions involving for example `max-width: 50%;` for `.box` are not what I'm looking for. My question is really about the table: Why does it not increase its width so that all of its contents fit properly into itself?

A solution for the problem should make sure that the table will not be "too wide": It should only be as wide as required so that the contents will just fit - but not a single subpixel wider.

Comment: I am looking into this at the moment, but your first mistake is `.flex { flex: 1 }`. This attribute is in the parent flexible container while `flex:` should be used in/on flexed child classes. Simply remove the line and you will see there is no change in behaviour. Move it to `.box` and you will see there is. This is not a solution (yet), just an observation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is explained in [9.2. Line Length Determination](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#line-sizing).

- First, the flex base size is determined for each item. This case it's complicated, because `width: 50%` depends on the available size. The spec says

  > If the used [flex basis](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis) is `content` or depends on its available
  >   size, and the flex container is being sized under a min-content or
  >   max-content constraint (e.g. when performing [automatic table
  >   layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout) [[CSS21]](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#biblio-css21)), size the item under that constraint. The
  >   [flex base size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-base-size) is the item’s resulting [main size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size).

  I'm not sure if that means the flex base size will be the min-content or max-content, because CSS tables use both. But since there are no wrap opportunities, both should be the same.

  So the flex base size will be the width of the text.
- Then,

  > Determine the [main size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size) of the flex container using the rules of
  >   the formatting context in which it participates.

  Then, the table and the flex container will be as wide as the sum of texts.

Once the width of the flex container has been established, the percentages of the flex items can be resolved. But they won't affect the width of the flex container (nor the table).

You can see this better in this snippet:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius: 9px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="">
          123456789ABCDEFGHIJKL
        </div>
        <div class="">
          meeedium
        </div>
        <div class="">
          short
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="box">
          123456789ABCDEFGHIJKL
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          meeedium
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          short
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Basically, what you want is make all flex items as wide as the widest one. I don't think there is a way to do that in CSS, but you can use JS.

Comment: I'll take a closer look at your answer later - but it seems that your answer finally gives an explanation for this behavior. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks again - your answer finally made me come up with a solution for my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566890/using-css-how-to-create-a-two-column-grid-with-equal-width-columns-that-are-on/34588007#34588007

Answer (score 18):

Actually, while I am not 100% sure about what you want, the solution seems to be close to my previous comment. Remove `flex: 1` from `.flex` and change `width:50%` in `.box` to `flex-basis: 50%`.

Oh, and while you're at it, add a space in the `123456789ABCDEF` so it can actually wrap....

```css
table {
  background-color: yellow;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px red;
  max-width: 100%;
  
  /* You would get similarly strange behavior with collapsing borders: */
  /* border-collapse: collapse; */
}

td {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px blue;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.flex {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
/* flex: 1;  REMOVE */
  background-color: lightblue;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  flex-basis: 50%; /* CHANGED from -> width: 50% */
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius: 9px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="box">
          123456789 ABCDEFGHIJKL <!-- NOTICE THE SPACE!!!!-->
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          meeedium
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          short
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use min-width on the box.  What are you trying to do exactly? why are you using tables? you could use normal floating divs for something like this and it wont face a lot of problem.

```css
#container {
  
  width:50%;

  }

.box{
  max-width:49%;
  float:left;
  border:solid 3px #ccc;
 }


 .clearfix {
   clear:both;
   }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
  28432412341341234
  </div>
    <div class="box">
  second boxxxxx
  </div>
    <div class="box">
  third boxxxxxxxxx
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Each box should actually have exactly the width that is half the width of the whole table. So I'm not looking for a solution to increase the width of a single box - but the width of the whole table. ~~~ Concerning what I'm trying to do exactly: Please have a look at the question that made my find this strangeness: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566890/using-css-how-to-create-a-two-column-grid-with-equal-width-columns-that-are-on) If there is a solution with "normal floating divs", please provide an example in an answer to the other question. It would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, now the grid is too wide, i.e. all cells have a lot of space that is unused. I require the table to be "as narrow as required", so that it is wide enough for the contents to fit but just not wider than that.

Comment: Thanks again - but now the grid cells do not all have the same width. (Or more precisely: No grid cell has exactly the width that is half the width of the whole grid.)

Comment: i honestly dont understand what you want to do. maybe if you can show a proper example or your project i could help you out.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566890/using-css-how-to-create-a-two-column-grid-with-equal-width-columns-that-are-on It includes a detailed description and a demonstration of what I'm trying to achieve.